# Creating a Primary Key Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ef-code-first

Hi I have a table (InspectionItemViolationCategories) that's being created as below using Entity Framework Code First, but now the situation came that I need to remove the unique requirement of both column combination and need to add a Primary Key with identity, any help please?

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<InspectionItem>()
        .HasMany(i => i.InspectionItemCategory).WithMany().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("InspectionItemId");
        m.MapRightKey("ViolationTypeId");
        m.ToTable("InspectionItemViolationCategories");
    });
```

There is no class exists with name InspectionItemViolationCategory as an entity, so need help